# Trouble with search functionality in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am trying to add a search functionality to my website. I have managed to add some of the search criteria that i needed however now the data in one of the columns called `Departments` in not showing for some reason. I think it might be due to there being two tables rather than one. Below is the code for my search function along with a screenshot of my problem.

Edit1
I have tried implementing lazy include like suggested so here is the code now, I have also attached a picture of my new error.[image]

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> SList(string search)
        {
            ViewData["GetStudentDetails"] = search;
            var studentquery = from x in _Db.tbl_Student.Include("tbl_Departments") select x;
            
            
            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
            {
                studentquery = studentquery.Where(x => x.FirstName.Contains(search) || x.Email.Contains(search));
              
            }
            return View(await studentquery.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync());
            
            
        }
```

Edit2
I have also tried writing "Departments" only as suggested but i still get the same error.

Edit3
Here are the pictures for my tables and my context[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does the `Department` field defined as a `foreign key`?

Comment: Yes it is. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to use `Include()` for lazy loading like in post below?

Comment: Can you show tbl_Student , tbl_department and the Context?

Answer (score 0):

Your context and classes are not correct.

You have 2 options: either use conventions or use fluent configuration.

In your case I would suggest going down the easy road an use conventions.

https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}



public class StudentContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Departments> Departments{ get; set; }

}
```

The naming has to match especially look for  plural forms

Comment: Thank you. I will change that and see if it fixes it.